# How to prevent upload from creating a version in sharepoint sp2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Whenever you upload a document in Sharepoint2010, a new version is created. I want to prevent this.

This is the code

```
upLoadedFile = listFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, data,false, comment,true);
```

Before this line, the file's MajorVersion is 0, immediately after that, it becomes 1.

Any ideas? I want the MajorVersion to be 0 after the code is executed.

Comment: Have you tried turning off versioning on the list?

Comment: I want versioning on, and do an upload programatically. If you use OOB to upload a document, there is only one version. Then why is it that by code, two versions are created?